example of how to expose nim GC_unref to a c backend
Recently, I picked up Nim and started experimenting with the backend integration features that the language offers and found myself at this page https://nim-lang.org/docs/backends.html where I got to the part at the very end that states "If you want to hand a Nim reference to C code, you will need to use GC_ref to mark the reference as used, so it does not get freed. And for the C backend you will need to expose the GC_unref proc to clean up this memory when it is not required anymore. However when I searched for an example I couldn't get anything to turn up.
I managed to compile a static library that could link with gcc and is capable of preserving a reference with GC_ref and demonstrating how a returned reference to collected memory behaves however my wrapper around GC_unref isn't functional. gist
`nim 

proc GC_unref_wrap*(i: cstring) {.exportcpp.} =
    GC_unref(cast[ref string](addr(i)))
proc gimmie*(): cstring {.exportcpp.} =
    var a:string = "gimmie"
    a.add " gimmie\n"
    return cstring(a)
proc gimmie_fixed*(): cstring {.exportcpp.} =
    var a: ref string = new(string)
    a[] = "gimmie"
    a[].add " gimmie"
    GC_ref(a)
    a[].add " gimmie\n"
    return cstring(a[])
proc use_memory*() {.exportcpp.} =
    GC_fullCollect()
    var tmp: string = ""
    for i in 0..100:
        for k in 0..100:
            tmp.add(char(k))
            
header

#ifndef HEADER_H
#define HEADER_H
extern void NimMain();
extern void GC_unref_wrap(void* i);
extern const char* gimmie();
extern void use_memory();
extern char* gimmie_fixed();
#endif

main cpp
 
#include "header.h"
#include <iostream>
 
void print_use_memory(){
    std::cout << "using memory clear\n";
}
int main(){
    NimMain();
    auto i = gimmie();
    std::cout << "gimmie before collect: " << i << "\n";
    auto i_fixed = gimmie_fixed();
    std::cout << "gimmie fixed before collect: " << i_fixed << "\n";
    print_use_memory();
    use_memory();
    std::cout << "gimmie after collect: " << i << "\n";
    std::cout << "gimmie fixed after collect: " << i_fixed << "\n";
    print_use_memory();
    std::cout << "unref gimmie fixed" << "\n";
    GC_unref_wrap(i_fixed);
    use_memory();
    std::cout << "gimmie fixed after unref and collect: " << i_fixed << "\n";
    return 0;
}`


I think the problem is you are presuming the address of a string type is the same as the address of a cstring type, due to the use of code like cast[ref string](addr(i)), where you are trying to cast the pointer of a cstring back into a string. However, this won't work without platform specific magic pointer arithmetic, because a cstring is a raw pointer to part of the memory held by the string.
Hopefully the following example makes the difference clear:
{.emit: """

#include <stdio.h>

void print_cpointer(char* x) {
  printf("C pointer %p '%s'\n\n", x, x);
}

void print_exported_string(NimStringDesc* x) {
  printf("Exported string %p '%s'\n\n", x, x);
}

""".}

proc print_cpointer(x: cstring): void {.importc.}
proc print_exported_string(x: string): void {.importc.}


proc test_address() =
  var
    a = "This is string a"
    b = "Another string"

  print_exported_string(a)
  print_cpointer(a.cstring)

  print_exported_string(b)
  print_cpointer(b.cstring)


proc main() =
  echo("Running nim main")
  test_address()
  echo("End of nim main")

when isMainModule: main()

Saving this code into a test.nim file I can run it like nim c  -r test.nim and it will produce the following output for me:
Running nim main
Exported string 0x10940f050 ''

C pointer 0x10940f060 'This is string a'

Exported string 0x109410050 ''

C pointer 0x109410060 'Another string'

End of nim main

From the output we can understand that cstring variables are actually 16 bytes later than their string variable memory address on my platform. Reading again through the explanation of cstring it mentions:

Even though the conversion is implicit, it is not safe: The garbage collector does not consider a cstring to be a root and may collect the underlying memory

As such, you should not try to GC_ref or GC_unref a cstring, and should pass the string directly (which for some reason is exported as NimStringDesc on my compiler version). Without looking at the internals we can probably asume a Nim string is a complex opaque structure with a trailing variable length null terminated array, and cstring just gives you the offset to that array skipping the metadata structure.
I tried understanding your C++ example but… couldn't. Here's at least a basic skeleton that tries to emulate a few of those calls you made, but incomplete and without knowing how it is meant to work I've just skipped most of it. But maybe you find it helpful:
proc GC_unref_wrap(x: ref string) {.exportc.} =
  GC_unref(x)

proc gimmie_mem(): ref string {.exportc.} =
  var a: ref string = new(string)
  a[] = "gimmie"
  a[].add " gimmie"
  GC_ref(a)
  result = a

proc use_memory() {.exportc.} =
  GC_fullCollect()
  var tmp = ""
  for i in 0..100:
    for k in 0..100:
      tmp.add(char(k))

proc c_main(): void {.importc: "c_main".}

{.emit: """

#include <stdio.h>

void c_main() {
  printf("Hey there from C\n");
  NimStringDesc** i = gimmie_mem();
  use_memory();
}

""".}


proc main() =
  echo("Running nim main")
  c_main()
  echo("End of nim main")

when isMainModule: main()

If you compile that with nim -c --header -r test.nim, you should find in your nim cache directory a another.h file with code like this:
/* section: NIM_merge_PROC_HEADERS */
N_LIB_PRIVATE N_NOCONV(void, signalHandler)(int sign);
N_LIB_PRIVATE N_NIMCALL(NI, getRefcount)(void* p);
N_LIB_PRIVATE N_NIMCALL(void, GC_unref_wrap)(NimStringDesc** x);
N_LIB_PRIVATE N_NIMCALL(NimStringDesc**, gimmie_mem)(void);
N_LIB_PRIVATE N_NIMCALL(void, use_memory)(void);

It's from this header that I figured out string is exported to C as NimStringDesc*. And a ref string will have a double pointer. All in all you'd have greater success exporting your own custom object types rather than the somehow magical cstring.
